# Saving website html content as text file on local disk error

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, save, disk

state_urls is dictionary where state is all the usa state names as a key and url is a url to info about them. The point of the below code is: for each key pair in the dict, to save a text file under the name of the state & for it to contain the html content of the link for that state key. Without the '.content' it works fine, but returns all the html from the page which is much more than I need, however once .content is added the error is AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'text'

```
for state, url in state_urls.items():

r = requests.get(url).content
with open(state_dir + state + '.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(r.text)
    
    sleep(2)
```

Comment: Use BeautifulSoup to parse ang get useful html, I had the same problem and this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

> AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'text'

Look what you have in variable `r` - if you use `requests.get(url)`, then it contains the `Response` object. If you use `requests.get(url).content` it will be the `content` property from `Response` object, which is text (or more precisely `bytes`) content of the webpage you downloaded.

You are trying to use the variable `r` a few lines lower again: `file.write(r.text)`. If the variable contains `Response` object, you can do that. However if you store there the `.content` property (which are `bytes`), it does not have `.text` property. This should work

```
r = requests.get(url) # dont use content
with open(state_dir + state + '.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(r.text) # r is Response, you can get its .text
    
    sleep(2)
```